# Lucene DocValues.Source deprecated

Tags: java, lucene

In lucene 4.0.0, org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues has DocValues.Source and DocValues.getSource().
But in lucene 8.1.0, org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues class does not have DocValues.Source and DocValues.getSource() any more. So how do I get the Source of the DocValues?

I have tried using org.apache.lucene.search.DocIdSetIterator but it doesn't help.
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.